# Como ler um arquivo XML com PHP?

Tags: php, xml

Olá, eu estou tentando ler um arquivo XML através de um link e não estou tendo sucesso.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
<h1>Vagas de Trabalho</h1>
<?php
    $link = "https://api.vulpi.com.br/media/feeds/linkedin.xml"; 
    //link do arquivo xml
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($link) -> source; 
    //carrega o arquivo XML e retornando um Array

    foreach($xml -> job as $item){ 

        echo "<strong>Empresa:</strong> "
        .utf8_decode($item -> company)."<br />";
        echo "<strong>Titulo:</strong> "
        .utf8_decode($item -> title)."<br />";
        echo "<strong>Descrição:</strong> "
        .utf8_decode($item -> description)."<br />";
        echo "<strong>Url:</strong> "
        .utf8_decode($item -> applyUrl)."<br />";
        echo "<strong>Lugar:</strong> "
        .utf8_decode($item -> location)."<br />";
        echo "<strong>Lugar:</strong> "
        .utf8_decode($item -> salary)."<br />";
        echo "<br />";
    } //fim do foreach
?>
</body>
</html>
```

ele da erro na linha 17:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\xml\vulpi.php on line 16
```

Eu olhei uns exemplos e para mim está certo..alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Ao analisar o XML o elemento *root* não entra na DOM, então não há a necessidade de acessar `-> source` como fez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa colocar `source` o que é retornado é tudo que está dentro dessa raiz, exemplo:

```
<?php
    $link = "https://api.vulpi.com.br/media/feeds/linkedin.xml"; 
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($link); 
    foreach($xml -> job as $item)
    {     
        echo "<strong>Empresa:</strong> "
        .utf8_decode($item -> company)."<br />";
        echo "<strong>Titulo:</strong> "
        .utf8_decode($item -> title)."<br />";
        echo "<strong>Descrição:</strong> "
        .utf8_decode($item -> description)."<br />";
        echo "<strong>Url:</strong> "
        .utf8_decode($item -> applyUrl)."<br />";
        echo "<strong>Lugar:</strong> "
        .utf8_decode($item -> location)."<br />";
        echo "<strong>Lugar:</strong> "
        .utf8_decode($item -> salary)."<br />";
        echo "<br />";
    } //fim do foreach
?>
```

Comment: obrigado! deu certo